# What is wrong with my function when I want to insert Croatian letters (č,ć,š,đ,ž) in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8

I have a problem with inserting data in mysql base. I am using code below. Everything is OK but when I insert "Croatian" letters (`č,ć,š,đ,ž`) I get wrong letters in base (something like this "`Ä,Ä‡,Å¡,Ä‘,Å¾`"). My mysql table is `utf8_croatian_ci`.

```
if (isset($_POST['nazivpredmeta'])) { 
$nazivpredmeta = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nazivpredmeta', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO predmet (ImePredmeta) VALUES (?)"))
   {
    $insert_stmt->bind_param('s', $nazivpredmeta); 
    if (! $insert_stmt->execute())
       { 
        header('Location: ../error.php?err=Greska: INSERT');
       } 
  } 
header('Location: ./index.php?page=predmeti&unospredmeta=OK');
}
```

But when I am using code below everthing is OK and for croatian letters I am getting correct letters.

```
if (isset($_POST['nazivpredmeta'])) { 
$naziv = $_POST['nazivpredmeta']; 
$sqlquery="INSERT INTO predmet (ImePredmeta) VALUES ('$naziv')"; 
$results = mysql_query($sqlquery); 
if (mysql_error()) echo "GREŠKA! ".mysql_errno().":".mysql_error(); 
}
```

My question is what is wrong with first code and what I need to edit in first code??? And short explanation

Comment: What is the table structure? Including data types.

Comment: Don't use `filter_input()`. It's one of those weird legacy PHP functions. You want literal values, because the db layer handles encoding etc. You can use mysqli statements (good!), but don't use `filter_input()`.

Comment: What encoding is the page using?

Comment: Table has two fields. First is primary_key(AUTO_INCREMENT) and second is ImePredmeta varchar(50),utf8_croatian_ci

Comment: Page has in <head> this link <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Answer (score 2):

It’s the use of the filter `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` in combination with anything else than pure ASCII, as I read from documentation.

```
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
```

sets the following filter_flags:

```
FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES, 
FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW, 
FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH, 
FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW, 
FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH, 
FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP
```

`FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW:` strips characters that has a numerical value <32
`FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH:` strips characters that has a numerical value >127

See the documentation on [filters sanitize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) and related documentation on [filter flags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php) for more information.

So this filter is only applicable to pure ASCII & should avoided at all.

Comment: Problem is not in filtering and filter flags. I try everything what you suggest but nothing happen or it is worst because now I have empty field in my base. This filters clear all input, nothing pass. And without filters I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `filter_input()`. It's one of those weird legacy PHP functions.

You want literal values, not 'filtered', because the db layer handles encoding etc. You can use mysqli statements (good!), but don't use `filter_input()`.

To see the difference, you should `var_dump()` both values:

```
var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nazivpredmeta', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
var_dump($_POST['nazivpredmeta']);
```

Using more functions isn't always better =)

Comment: I try your suggest but nothing.

Comment: Did you do the `var_dump()`s? What's the difference? Add it to the question.

Comment: Add the output to the question. It can't be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try: utf8_encode(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nazivpredmeta', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

Comment: I try your suggest but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure the connecting is `UTF8` before you run the actual query. So this:

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO predmet (ImePredmeta) VALUES (?)"))
```

Would change to this:

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SET NAMES UTF8; INSERT INTO predmet (ImePredmeta) VALUES (?)"))
```

Or perhaps do it this way:

```
$mysqli->query($this->connecDB, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO predmet (ImePredmeta) VALUES (?)"))
```

Also, unrelated but worth pointing out is in he first chunk of code you are making calls to `$mysqli->prepare()` but in the next—where you say things are working—you are using `mysql_query()`. While not 100% technically wrong, you are mixing the `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` extensions by doing this which can cause inadvertent confession in cases like this.  You should stick to `mysqli_*` since `mysql_*` is depreciated and will be eliminated in PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Before everything I just add $mysqli->set_charset('utf8'); 
And now both codes working.